# URL Amigavel com .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url, url-amigável

Gostaria de deixar minha url que é assim:
https://assistir.xyz/embed/filme.php?id=tt0120737
para ficar assim 
https://assistir.xyz/embed/tt0120737

Tem como deixar algum fazer um arquivo .htaccess pra mim

Answer (score 1):

Bom pelo que entendi quer algo easy way. Segue um modo easy way de fazer. Contudo recomendo realmente estudar e aprender como funciona o htaccess.

http://www.htaccesseditor.com/pt.shtml#a_fileList

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/pt-br/howto/htaccess.html

Reescrevendo URL pelo .htaccess: Extensão .php

Para você retirar o “.php” da sua URL e usufruir de um link amigável, basta inserir as seguintes linhas:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Reescrevendo URL pelo .htaccess: Extensão .html

Para você retirar o “.html” da sua URL e usufruir de um link amigável, você pode simplesmente inserir a seguinte linha:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Se você comparar os dois códigos você vai reparar que na linha RewriteRule há um $1.php no primeiro exemplo e um $1.html no segundo. Percebemos que é neste trecho do código que a “magia” de esconder a extensão acontece.